# How can I sort json data for dumping?

Tags: python, arrays, json, flask

I am trying to dump JSON data in Python to a file.
I receive the data as an *ImmutableMultiDict* from a Flask post request.
It looks as follows: *ImmutableMultiDict([('prefix', ''), ('key1', 'value1'), ('key2', 'value2')])*
The data should look like this in the file:

```
{ "prefix": [
    {"key1": "value1"},
    {"key2" : "value2"}
  ]
}
```

The prefix as well as all the other data is part of the post request. My question now is: How can I *json.dump* the ImmutableMultiDict so it appears like this in the file? Right now it looks like this:

```
{
    "prefix": "",
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
}
```

The reason why I want to do it the other way is because I want to append data later on by appending it to the array with the "prefix" key. Can anyone show me a way to do this properly please?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Ok. I fixed it so it looks the way it should now. The Python code:

```
def write_to_json(file, data, prefix):
    with open(file, "a", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        json.dump({prefix : list(data)}, f, indent=4)
```

Result:

```
{
    "prefix": [
        "key1",
        "key2"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you did not mentioned anything about it, I'd recommend to check `ImmutableMultiDict#to_dict()` with `flat` parameter, see [documentation](https://tedboy.github.io/flask/generated/generated/werkzeug.ImmutableMultiDict.to_dict.html#werkzeug.ImmutableMultiDict.to_dict).

Maybe I am understanding incorrectly, but are you trying to have multiple keys for "prefix"? This is opposing to the definition of JSON and will not work as the keys of a dict (MultiDict) uses something like a set for store their keys.

Comment: Sry if I described my problem in a confusing way. I am trying to have a key ("prefix") and a list of dictionaries as the value. I will take a look at the to_dict() method.

Comment: Can you show me a bigger example what the data looks like and should look like?

Comment: I created a [paste](https://pastebin.com/xMKGe1y9) in which I described how it should look and how it looks now. The amount of data is irrelevant considering the fact that this post is about appending the data to the list of dictionaries.

Comment: I got the solution and edited my question. Anything more than that (concerning the final json code) is just tweaking of the json.dump line.